# Send Email html with iterated model data

Tags: django

I am trying to set up an email alert that sends once a week. I intend to set a cronjob for a this function so it will do so.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def send_email():
    try:
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From'] = "<email>"
        msg['To'] = "<email>"
        msg['Subject'] = "sub"

        html = """
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p> hello</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

        msg.attach(part1)
        mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.email.client", 587, timeout=20)
        mail.starttls()

        recepient = ['<email>']

        mail.login('<email>', '<password>')
        mail.sendmail("fromemail@domain.com", recepient, msg.as_string())
        mail.quit()

    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

I am trying to have the html mirror one of my templates in my project, and in this template I am iterating over model data to create charts.

views.py

```
class TestView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "test.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TestView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['testrail'] = TestRail.objects.all()
        return context
```

test.html

```
    <body>
<h1>4.2.0 Test Plan</h1>
{% for x in testrail %}
<h3>{{x.component}}</h3>
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh"></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">#</th>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td class="tg-hmp3">Total</td>
    <td class="tg-hmp3">{{x.total_count}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-hmp3">Passed</td>
    <td class="tg-hmp3">{{x.passed_count}}</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Untested</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.untested_count}}</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Failed</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.failed_count}}</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Reviewed</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.reviewed_count}}</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Harness Failures</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.test_harness_issue_count}}</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Product Failures</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.bug_failure_count}}</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Coverage %</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.coverage_percentage}}%</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Passed %</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.passed_percentage}}%</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Reviewed %</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.reviewed_percentage}}%</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Harness Failure %</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.harness_percentage}}%</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Product Failure %</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">{{x.product_failure_percentage}}%</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Now i am having trouble figuring out how to be able to mirror what i have above because it is using model data, and using a css file.

I don't necessarily need the .css file to work but want to know how to be able to show model data in the html part of the email message.

How could I be able to iterate and show model data (like in my template) in the email message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Django's mailing system. It uses the smtplib but will save you the headache of handling the specifics. Just add the basic settings in settings.py

```
# SMTP Host settings
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_PORT = ''

# if your SMTP host needs authentication
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''

# Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and
# EMAIL_PORT settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings, if
# set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS and
# EMAIL_USE_SSL settings control whether a secure connection is used.
```

then you can simply do:

```
   from django.template.loader import render_to_string
   from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

   def send_email():
        context = {}
        subject = "subject"
        from_email = "from@email.com"
        body_template = "template.html"
        body = render_to_string(body_template, context).strip()
        to_emails = ["list of emails"]
        email = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, to_emails)
        email.content_subtype = "html"
        email.send()
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I had to user `loader.render_to_string` for this to work... i would add the imports to this answer as well `from django.template import loader` and `from django.core.mail import EmailMessage`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `render_to_string` method from django templates to render your html and context into a string like this.

```
from django.template import loader

text = loader.render_to_string(<TEMPLATE_NAME>, {'x': <MODEL_INSTANCE>})
```

Send text with your email as want.

Comment: Is there anyway I am able to do this but have it return html and not a string? So i can use the context and insert html to the email message....  Using this answer will not make use of my html tags and will show them as strings in the message

Comment: You can use `send_mail` function provided by django to send your email. You can pass `html`  to it. It will attach it properly. Read more detail in [docs] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail).